# Subclassing file class in Python raises NameError

Tags: python, file, subclass

I have to do a very simple project in python where I add error checking to the built in file class.  So far, I've got:

```
class RobustFile(file):
    def __init__(self,name,mode):
        file.__init__(self,name,mode)
```

I'm just starting out, but to make sure I hadn't messed anything up, I ran it.  Well, right off the bat, I raised a NameError because it didn't recognize file.  I tried tweaking it, I looked it up on the internet, I copied examples using the same format, and...all NameError.  Can anyone shed some light on how exactly to subclass file?

Comment: That's an odd project: the built-in file class in Python already has error checking.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? This example runs fine using Python 2.6.5 on Windows.

Answer (score 7):

You're probably using Python 3, which no longer has a `file` type.

Instead, as noted in the [Python 3 documentation's I/O Overview](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/io.html#io-overview), it has a number of different stream types that are all derived from one of `_io.TextIOBase`, `_io.BufferedIOBase`, or `_io.RawIOBase`, which are themselves derived from `_io.IOBase`.

Comment: OUTSTANDING! Thank you so much! Thats so helpful! I can finally finish my project! yep! I've got it working in 2.6!

Answer (score 1):

Works fine in python 2.6.6:

```
In [44]: class RobustFile(file):
    def __init__(self,name,mode):
        file.__init__(self,name,mode)
   ....: 

In [47]: fp = RobustFile('foo','w')

In [48]: fp.writelines('bar')

In [49]: fp.close()
```